# Cypress: Access objects inside a array in API request

Tags: arrays, json, api, cypress

I requested a POST method in API call for login test and received array with many objects in the body. I wanna access a specific client token using **its** method, but it is inside a array and I cannot quite figure out how to access, because the array doesn't have a "name".

The request in cypress:

```
it('Logar em um cliente com um usuário', function () {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://localhost:44332/api/Users/LoginDefault',
        body: {
            "username": "user",
            "password": "password"
        }
    }).its('body.token').then(res => console.log(res))
```

The body response (resumed):

```
[
    {
        "user": "user1",
        "token": "token1"
    },
    {
        "user": "user2",
        "token": "token2"
    },
    {
        "user": "user3",
        "token": "token3"
    }
]
```

*SOLUTION*
It worked like this:

```
    it('Logar em um cliente com um usuário', function () {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://localhost:44332/api/Users/LoginDefault',
            body: {
                "username": "user",
                "password": "password"
            }
        }).its('body').then((res) => {
             const dadoToken = res[1].token
             expect(dadoToken).not.to.be.empty
        }) 
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation that body response is an array, so all you need to do is navigate the array.

The return value is `res`, so in this situation, it would be `res[i].token` where `i` is the object in the array that you require.

For example `res[2].token` would be "token3".

Answer (score 1):

In my case of a standard Web API project in .NET, the JSON response on the Cypress side has the property `body`, so you cannot use simply `res[i]`, but you should use `res.body[i]`. Then you can write following example tests:

```js
  it('supports getting data from API', () => {
    cy.request('http://localhost:5186/api/users').as('users')

    cy.get('@users').should((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      expect(response).to.have.property('status')
      expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
      expect(response).to.have.property('body')
      expect(response.body).to.be.an('Array')
      expect(response.body).to.have.length.of.at.least(1)
      expect(response.body[0]).to.have.property('user')
      expect(response.body[0].pesel).eq('user1')
    })
  })
```